# Parametrising $x+y+z=1$ subject to $x,y,z \ge 0$ with one variable $t$

Tags: vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

Title says it all. I am to find the contour integral

$$\oint_C \vec F(\vec r)\  \cdot d\vec r$$

For the surface ascribed in the title. To do this, I am to parametrise $x$, $y$, and $z$ as a function of $t$. Given the equation,

$$x=1-y-z$$
$$y=1-x-z$$
$$z=1-x-y$$

I don't see any way this can be parametrised with one variable.

Comment: $x+y+z = 1$ plus $x,y,z \ge 0$ defines a surface (in fact a triangle), not a line. Instead of the whole area, are you trying to parametrize the sides?

Comment: @achillehui Ah, yes, I believe so. The answer doesn't become any clearer to me though.

Comment: In that case, you can parametrize each side individually and merge the parametrizations into one by suitable shifting of the parameters. e.g.
 $$(x,y,z) = \begin{cases}
(1-t,t,0),&t \in [0,1]\\
(0,1-(t-1),t-1) = (0,2-t,t-1),&t \in [1,2]\\
(t-2,0,1-(t-2)) = (t-2,0,3-t),&t \in [2,3]
\end{cases}$$